# Is there a set of integers where all differences are relatively prime?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Is there an infinite subset $\mathcal S\subset \mathbb Z$ with the property that for any 4-tuple of distinct elements $x,y,z,w\in \mathcal S$ 
$$
\gcd(x-y,z-w)=1?
$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I guess the lack of any indication of work you put in it. A question does look much better if there is already at least a hint in it that describes what you tried and possibly where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok, that's a fair point. I'll try to add more details next time. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $x,y,z,w$ are distinct and either all odd or all even, then the two differences are both even, and so $\gcd(x-y,z-w)\geq 2$. On the other hand, if $\mathcal{S}$ is infinite, then it contains either infinitely many even numbers or infinitely many odd numbers.

Comment: By similar reasoning, we can also determine the maximum number of elements possible for $S$.

Comment: Cool. In fact, $|S|$ can have at most 6 elements, by your argument.